# Why is the point() function slightly transparent?

Tags: processing

I'm running this code:

```java
void draw() {

  if (mousePressed) {
    background(255, 0, 0);
  } else {
    background(0, 255, 0);
  }

  stroke(200, 200, 200);

  for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      point(x, y);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm drawing a red or green background, and then I'm setting the color to gray (a color with an r, g, and b of 200) and then looping over every pixel in the window and drawing a point over top of the background, so I would expect to only see a gray background.

Instead, what I'm seeing is a "slightly green" or "slightly red" window. In other words, I can see the background color through the gray points.

[image: green and red showing through]

It looks like the `point()` function is drawing points with a transparency, but my stroke color is `200, 200, 200`.

If I change the call to `point()` to `rect(x, y, 1, 1)` then I see the solid gray like I would expect.

I see this problem in both Processing 2.2.1 and 3.1.1, but I don't see it in Processing.js.

Am I missing something with the `point()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh, I figured this out as soon as I posted the question. The problem is that by default the points are anti-aliased, which results in making them slightly transparent.

Calling the `noSmooth()` function from `setup()` fixes the problem.

```java
void setup(){
  noSmooth();
}
```

D'oh. More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/noSmooth_.html) if anybody has the same problem.